# if or after you are ready

Tags: conjunctions, conditionals

> Question 17 We can go _____ you’re ready.
>
> A) if     B) after    C) before     D) while

The answer to the question above is "after". But what about "if"? Which is used by the natives?

Comment: @JamesK, Personally I'd prefer to go after I was ready than before I was ready!

Comment: Thanks a lot, everybody!

Comment: What is the source of this test question.

Comment: I don't like any of them much. I'd prefer 'once' or 'when'.

Comment: "If" also sounds fine to me. They mean different things, so perhaps there is some context indicating what it should mean.

Comment: Hello loloist, and welcome to ELL. This Question 17 is a terrible question because all of the answers are correct, and two of them are quite natural. This test was prepared by someone who is not trained in producing teaching material. Do you want to learn the grammar, or do you just want to confirm that the test question is bad?

Answer (score 4):

Yet another bad exercise. To me as a native speaker, "We can go if you're ready" is perfectly idiomatic (it functions as a question "Are you ready yet? If so, we can go.")

"We can go after you are ready" is not at all idiomatic. It would be very inconsiderate to leave *before* one member of the party was ready! *When* would be much better.

Answer (score -1):

'after' can be used if the person asking has determined they are ready.

'if' can be used if the person being asked is ready.

Comment: Hey Greg, and welcome to ELL. We appreciate you took the time to answer, but honestly, this isn't a great one. Please make sure your wording is clear, and give more detail to explain what you mean. For instance, what do you mean, "*the person asking*"? Do you mean, the person speaking? "*We can go after you're ready*" isn't a question, so nobody is asking. Also, who is "they"? The person speaking, or the person they're talking to? Please give more detail what it means to use "if", including implied things that aren't in the words themselves.